# My object within an object definition is not working

Tags: javascript, oop

Below is a faulty hardcoded example of a game object. The game object is suppose to contain an array like object of players. It’s obvious what the intention is here but so far I am getting it wrong. 
I have tried swapping out the players brackets w/ braces, and or the equal sign with a colon.

What is the problem here?

```
var game = {
    gameName : 'Name of Game Instance',
    players : {
       player1  : {
         name:"Tom",
         score:0
       },
       player2  : {
         name:"Bob",
         score:0
       },
       player3  : {
         name:"Ziggy",
         score:0
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Syntactically, there is nothing wrong with the posted code.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's not at all obvious what your  intention is here because this code works and does exactly what it is specified to do.  Please describe the desired outcome.  All these answers so far are pure guesses as to what you actually want.

Comment: @jfriend00 he is trying to make `game.players` an array, i feel that the question is clear enough if you read it carefully.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh - It is not clear.  He said he tried brackets and braces, but doesn't explain what he's trying to achieve.  And, he clearly defines indexes `player1:`, `player2:`, etc... which are not at all consistent with an array.  You are guessing.  The question is not clear.

Comment: i'm getting in an error in JS console., please remove the DOWN vote!

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - referencing the line where players object begins

Comment: i'm sorry i had the keyword VAR in front of the players object. that was creating an error. can i withdraw the question? or should i edit?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `players` to be an array of objects:

```
var game = {
    gameName : 'Name of Game Instance',
    players : [
       {
         name:"Tom",
         score:0
       },
       {
         name:"Bob",
         score:0
       },
       {
         name:"Ziggy",
         score:0
       }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `game.players` is an object, hence you do not have array methods on it such as `forEach` and `.length`.

to make it an array, you cannot simply swap the `{ ... }` with `[ ... ]` since arrays do not accept key-value pairs, they accept only values, and their key implicitly is their index. to be able to access each player, you can make the array an **array of objects** like this to do array stuff on `game.players` since they are arrays.

```
var game = {
    gameName : 'Name of Game Instance',
    players : [
       {
         name:"Tom",
         score:0
       },
       {
         name:"Bob",
         score:0
       },
       {
         name:"Ziggy",
         score:0
       }
    ]
 }
```

if you wish to keep it as an object, you can take its keys in an array form writing the following:

```
Object.keys(game.players).forEach(function(key) {
   var currentPlayer = game.players[key]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var game = {
gameName : 'Name of Game Instance',
players : [
    {
        name: "Tom",
        score: 0
    },
    {
        name: "Bob",
        score: 0
    },
    {
        name: "Ziggy",
        score: 0
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.

Answer (score -1):

Having the players as a array of objects. Something like this:

```
var game = {
    gameName : 'Name of Game Instance',
    players : [
        {
            name: "Tom",
            score: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Bob",
            score: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Ziggy",
            score: 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.